# Executable Buttons Not Displaying

Tags: vb.net

I created a VB.Net application with a target .NET Framework of 4.5. The application runs fine on my computer (or any system with Visual Studio installed). But when I try to run the exe generated from the build, the application loads, but the buttons are not displaying. There is an outline where the button is, and you can actually click the button to perform the action just fine. I assume this has something to do with a reference problem, but I really don't know for sure. They are just standard Windows form buttons. No images attached.

Comment: Are you including the images for the buttons in the deployment?

Comment: Use Task Manager, look at the CPU usage of your program.  It probably burns 100% core, generating paints events at a very high rate.  Never getting to the button.

Comment: @WorkSmarter They are just the standard Windows Forms button with no image attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the solution, but not necessarily the problem. The button had a BackColor property set to Black which is the same color as the form. For some reason, on certain machines this caused the button and the form to blend together. Changing the button BackColor to something different (such as Control grey) worked just fine.